# when trying to create a bitmap: _tkinter.TclError: bitmap "pyimage2" not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

There is an image which I'd like to draw in different colors, so I converted it to a bitmap, but when trying to create it on the canvas I get an error.

This is the code:

```
import PIL.Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import *


im = PIL.Image.open("lightbulb.gif")
small_im = im.resize((20,20), resample=PIL.Image.NEAREST).convert('1');

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root,width=100,height=100,bg='black')
canvas.pack()
bitmap = ImageTk.BitmapImage(small_im)
bitmap_id = canvas.create_bitmap(3,3,background='', foreground='gray', bitmap=bitmap,
                                 anchor=NW)
root.mainloop()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ronen/Dropbox/trycanvas/bitmaps.py", line 13, in <module>
    bitmap_id = canvas.create_bitmap(3,3,background="", foreground="gray", bitmap=bitmap, anchor=NW)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2486, in create_bitmap
    return self._create('bitmap', args, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2480, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "pyimage2" not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I now understand what's going on. `ImageTk.BitmapImage` actually return an image, not a bitmap, but it can be used to change the colors. So intead of:

```
bitmap = ImageTk.BitmapImage(small_im)
bitmap_id = canvas.create_bitmap(3,3,background='', foreground='gray', bitmap=bitmap,
                                 anchor=NW)
```

I should have coded:

```
from_bitmap = ImageTk.BitmapImage(small_im, background='', foreground='gray')
bitmap_id = canvas.create_image(3,3, image=from_bitmap, anchor=NW)
```

Answer (score 3):

The tkinter `canvas.create_bitmap()` method expects its `bitmap=` option to be a *string* containing either the **name** of one of the standard bitmaps (which are `'error'`, `'gray75'`, `'gray50'`, `'gray25'`, `'gray12'`, `'hourglass'`, `'info'`, `'questhead'`, `'question'`, and `'warning'`) and which  look like this:

[image: image showing the standard bitmaps graphically]

***Or*** the pathname of a file with one of your own in it in `.xbm` file format prefixed with an `@` character.

Below is how to modify your code so it saves the image you want to display in a temporary `.xbm` format file and then tells tkinter to use that:

```
import os
import PIL.Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import tkinter as tk

im = PIL.Image.open("lightbulb.gif")
small_img = im.resize((20,20), resample=PIL.Image.NEAREST).convert('1');

with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.xbm', delete=False) as temp_img:
    small_img.save(temp_img.name)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100, bg='black')
canvas.pack()
bitmap_id = canvas.create_bitmap(3, 3, background='', foreground='gray',
                                 bitmap='@'+temp_img.name, anchor=tk.NW)
root.mainloop()

try:  # Cleanup
    os.remove(temp_img.name)  # Get rid of named temporary file.
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks @martineau, your answer made me question what `ImageTk.BitmapImage` does in the first place, and helped me get my own answer, without using a temporary file.

Comment: Sorry, @martinieau, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, and I rather accept my own answer (I don't think I can accept two of them.)

Comment: rantash68: Oops, forgot about that restriction...maybe now? (FWIW, I agree your answer is better—I didn't suggest it because I didn't understand enough about what you were trying to accomplish by creating a `BitmapImage`.)